# Weird shape requirement for `sample_weight` argument in Keras losses in TF2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras

According to TF document, the the `sample_weight` argument can have shape `[batch_size]`. The relevant documentation is quoted below:

> `sample_weight`: Optional `Tensor` whose rank is either 0, or the same rank as `y_true`, or is broadcastable to `y_true`. `sample_weight` acts as a coefficient for the loss. If a scalar is provided, then the loss is simply scaled by the given value. If `sample_weight` is a tensor of size `[batch_size]`, then the total loss for each sample of the batch is rescaled by the corresponding element in the `sample_weight` vector. If the shape of `sample_weight` matches the shape of `y_pred`, then the loss of each measurable element of `y_pred` is scaled by the corresponding value of `sample_weight`.

However, I cannot understand why the following code does not work.

```
import tensorflow as tf

gt = tf.convert_to_tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
pred = tf.convert_to_tensor([1., 0., 1., 1., 0.])
sample_weights = tf.convert_to_tensor([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])

loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()(gt, pred, sample_weight=sample_weights)
print(loss)
```

The code throw this error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 5 [Op:Squeeze]

If I expand the dimensions of `gt`, `pred`, and `sample_weights`, then it works properly and output the expected loss value of 3.0849898.

```
import tensorflow as tf

gt = tf.convert_to_tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
pred = tf.convert_to_tensor([1., 0., 1., 1., 0.])
sample_weights = tf.convert_to_tensor([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])

# expand dims
gt = tf.expand_dims(gt, 1)
pred = tf.expand_dims(pred, 1)
sample_weights = tf.expand_dims(sample_weights, 1)

loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()(gt, pred, sample_weight=sample_weights)
print(loss)  # loss is 3.0849898
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not about `sample_weight` shape. It's `pred` and `gt` shape which should be `[batch_size, n_labels]`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

gt = tf.convert_to_tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
pred = tf.convert_to_tensor([1., 0., 1., 1., 0.])
sample_weights = tf.convert_to_tensor([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])

# expand dims
gt = tf.expand_dims(gt, 1)
pred = tf.expand_dims(pred, 1)
print(gt.shape, pred.shape) #(5, 1) (5, 1)

loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()(gt, pred, sample_weight=sample_weights)
print(loss)  # loss is 3.0849898
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, while I believe this is certainly true for multi-label calssification, this is counter intuitive in `BinaryCrossentropy` where you don't need an extra dimension `n_labels`. More importantly, the [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy) kinda implies that you shouldn't need the extra dimension. Maybe its just poor documentation?

Comment: @HongtaoYang I think they overlooked this case when they were working on sample_weight implementation, since the problem occurs only when sample_weight is present.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I just add an extra dimension for now.